# TensorFlow: parameters do not update when training

Tags: python, ocr, tensorflow

I'm implementing a classification model using TensorFlow

The problem that I'm facing is that my weights and error are not being updated when I run the training step. As a result, my network keeps returning the same results.

I've developed my model based on the [MNIST example](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html) from the TensorFlow website.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

#load dataset
dataset = np.loadtxt('char8k.txt', dtype='float', comments='#', delimiter=",")
Y = np.asmatrix( dataset[:,0] ) 
X = np.asmatrix( dataset[:,1:1201] )

m = 11527
labels = 26

# y is update to 11527x26
Yt = np.zeros((m,labels))

for i in range(0,m):
    index = Y[0,i] - 1
    Yt[i,index]= 1

Y = Yt
Y = np.asmatrix(Y)

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#graph settings

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1200])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 26])


Wtest = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1200,26], stddev=0.001))
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1200,26], stddev=0.001))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([26]))
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)

cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)
Wtest = W


for i in range(10):
  print("iteracao:")
  print(i)
  Xbatch = X[np.random.randint(X.shape[0],size=100),:]
  Ybatch = Y[np.random.randint(Y.shape[0],size=100),:]
  train_step.run(feed_dict={x: Xbatch, y_: Ybatch})
  print("atualizacao de pesos")  
  print(Wtest==W)#monitora atualizaçao dos pesos

  correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
  accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
  print("precisao:Y")
  print accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: X, y_: Y})
  print(" ")
  print(" ")
```

Comment: You probably should ask your question in english.

Comment: Questions on www.stackoverflow.com should be in English.

Comment: Você pode ir ao site [português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) ou pedir em Inglês.

Comment: my mistake guys, i'll edit my question, thanks

Comment: `print(Wtest==W)` will always give you 'true', since Wtest and W are the same variable

Comment: but W should be updated in each iteration of the for loop

Comment: `Wtest` and `W` point to the same object. In Python-lingo they are different *names* for the *same object*. You should probably remove the `Wtest=W` line.

Answer (score 5):

The issue probably arises from how you initialize the weight matrix, `W`. If it is initialized to all zeroes, all of the neurons will follow the same gradient in each step, which leads to the network not training. Replacing the line

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1200,26]))
```

...with something like

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1200,26], stddev=0.001))
```

...should cause it to start training.

[This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27112/danger-of-setting-all-initial-weights-to-zero-in-backpropagation) on the CrossValidated site has a good explanation of why you should not initialize all of your weights to zero.

Comment: i'm still getting the same results, stuck on 0.10996 precision, but i'll edit my question's code with your sugestion

Comment: Have a look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127436/tensorflow-predicts-always-the-same-result/36134261#36134261 ... the user was having the same problem as you, and you could also try running mini-batches through the system, rather than the entire dataset at once. Using `tf.reduce_sum()` rather than `tf.reduce_mean()` to compute the overall loss could be giving you too large of an effective learning rate as well.

Comment: Great answer! I was trying the same thing and followed your suggestions. But still I am facing the same problem. Could you please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501513/tensorflow-weights-and-biases-are-not-updating-when-tried-with-following-code