# What is the default kernel initializer in tf.layers.conv2d and tf.layers.dense?

Tags: tensorflow

The official Tensorflow API doc claims that the parameter `kernel_initializer` defaults to `None` for `tf.layers.conv2d` and `tf.layers.dense`.

However, reading the layers tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers), I noted that this parameter is not set in the code. For example:

```py
# Convolutional Layer #1
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
    inputs=input_layer,
    filters=32,
    kernel_size=[5, 5],
    padding="same",
    activation=tf.nn.relu)
```

The example code from the tutorial runs without any errors, so I think the default `kernel_initializer` is not `None`. So, which initializer is used?

In another code, I did not set the `kernel_initializer` of the conv2d and dense layers, and everything was fine. However, when I tried to set the `kernel_initializer` to `tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1, dtype=tf.float32)`, I got NaN errors. What is going on here? Can anyone help?

Comment: Maybe the NaN has different reason? I'm using kernel_initializer = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.001, dtype=tf.float32) and it works as expected.

Answer (score 110):

Great question! It is quite a trick to find out!

- As you can see, it is not documented in [`tf.layers.conv2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv2d)
- If you look at the definition of [the function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/layers/convolutional.py) you see that the function calls `variable_scope.get_variable`:

In code:

```py
self.kernel = vs.get_variable('kernel',
                                  shape=kernel_shape,
                                  initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
                                  regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer,
                                  trainable=True,
                                  dtype=self.dtype)
```

Next step: [what does the variable scope do when the initializer is None?](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py)

Here it says:

> If initializer is `None` (the default), the default initializer passed in
>       the constructor is used. If that one is `None` too, we use a new
>       `glorot_uniform_initializer`.

So the answer is: it uses the [`glorot_uniform_initializer`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py)

For completeness the definition of this initializer:

> The Glorot uniform initializer, also called Xavier uniform initializer.
>     It draws samples from a uniform distribution within [-limit, limit]
>     where `limit` is `sqrt(6 / (fan_in + fan_out))`
>     where `fan_in` is the number of input units in the weight tensor
>     and `fan_out` is the number of output units in the weight tensor.
>     Reference: http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf

Edit: this is what I found in the code and documentation. Perhaps you could verify that the initialization looks like this by running eval on the weights!

Comment: I had the same question. Based on the kernel graphs in the tensorboard, it seems the kernels are initialized from some uniform distribution.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s2coXdufOzE) by Andrew Ng and the [Xavier documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/xavier_initializer), if you are using **ReLU** as activation function, better change the default weights initializer(which is **Xavier uniform**) to **Xavier normal** by:

```
y = tf.layers.conv2d(x, kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=False), )
```

Comment: which is `keras.initializers.glorot_normal(seed=None)` or simply `kernel_initializer= 'glorot_normal'` inside `Conv2D`  in keras.

Comment: glorot_uniform_initializer is Xavier normal? Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 1):

**2.0 Compatible Answer**: Even in Tensorflow 2.0, the Default **`Kernel Initializer`** in `tf.keras.layers.Conv2D` and `tf.keras.layers.Dense` is **`glorot_uniform`**.

This is specified in the Tensorflow.org Website.

Link for **`Conv2D`** is [https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D?version=nightly#**init**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D?version=nightly#__init__)

and the Link for **`Dense`** is

[https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense?version=nightly#**init**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense?version=nightly#__init__)