# tf.layers.conv2d: Are use_bias=False and bias_initializer=None the same?

Tags: tensorflow

From what I can tell, [tf.layers.conv2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv2d) has two different ways of disabling biases: setting `use_bias=False` and setting `bias_initializer=None`.

Are these the same, or do they do different things? Do I need to use both?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure `bias_initializer=None` can disable bias

a little test

```
data = np.random.rand(2, 5, 8, 3).astype(np.float32)
tensor = tf.constant(data)
n = tf.layers.conv2d(tensor, 10, 3, 1, bias_initializer=None)
tfvar = tf.trainable_variables()
# tfvar 
# [<tf.Variable 'conv2d/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 3, 10) dtype=float32_ref>, 
# <tf.Variable 'conv2d/bias:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

even set `bias_initializer=None`, get bias as trainable variables

Answer (score 0):

You can either set `use_bias = False` or set `bias_initializer=None` to disable bias. I think the first one is more intuitive. However, not setting `bias_initializer` will make it zeros and not setting `kernel_initializer` will make it `glorot_uniform` according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43284047/what-is-the-default-kernel-initializer-in-tf-layers-conv2d-and-tf-layers-dense) answer.