# What is the default value of bias_initializer for GRUCell in tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

GRUCell provides an option for initializing bias using bias_initializer which is set to 'None'. But, according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/43284391/7730199, the default would actually not be 'None', but 'glorot_uniform_initializer'. That discussion happened in the context of kernel_initializer. Will the same apply to bias_initializer of GRUCell too?

Also, what is the best initialization for biases in GRUCell?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is constant ones:

```
 def call(self, inputs, state):
    """Gated recurrent unit (GRU) with nunits cells."""
    if self._gate_linear is None:
      bias_ones = self._bias_initializer
      if self._bias_initializer is None:
        bias_ones = init_ops.constant_initializer(1.0, dtype=inputs.dtype)
```

From https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c646af1957197a9be0feb5e928af46e29da688ea/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py#L313