# kernel_initializer in tf.layers api

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am using the `tf.layers` api for defining convolution and other layers in my network. One thing that I stumbled upon is the `kernel_initializer` option for the convolution layers. Does this parameter refer to the `weights` for the convolution layer? If yes, then does this mean that I can directly pass the weight matrix to that layer?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, you can implement the initializer by yourself.

some discussions about this topic

- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9744
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43284391/456105