# tf.layers.conv2d and tf.nn.conv2d Different outputs with same architecture

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, convolution

Note: I read the similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42785026/tf-nn-conv2d-vs-tf-layers-conv2d), but it doesn't cover my use case.

I'm building a GAN and am converting my discriminator design from using tf.nn.conv2d (following some example code) to tf.layers.conv2d. Both designs use the same inputs, kernel sizes, strides, yet I'm getting different results between the two.

Both versions should be 28x28x1 input -> conv2d with a 5x5 kernel, 2 stride, 16 layers, leaky relu -> conv2d with a 3x3 kernel, 2 stride, 32 layers, leaky relu -> flatten to 7*7*32 -> 256 neuron dense network with leaky relu -> 1 value output.

I've checked the weight initialization. tf.layers.conv2d defaults to 
xaiver init as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43284047/what-is-the-default-kernel-initializer-in-tf-layers-conv2d-and-tf-layers-dense).

layers version:

```
def discriminator(x):
# Reshape to a 28x28 image with one layer of depth (greyscale)
x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])

with tf.variable_scope('discriminator',  reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE) as scope:

    # Defaults to Xavier init for weights and Zeros for bias
    disc_conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs = x,
        filters = 16,
        kernel_size=5,
        strides=2,
        padding="same",
        activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu
    )
    disc_conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs = disc_conv1,
        filters = 32,
        kernel_size=3,
        strides=2,
        padding="same",
        activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu
    )
    disc_conv2 = tf.reshape(disc_conv2, shape=[-1, 7 * 7 * 32])
    disc_h1 = tf.layers.dense(disc_conv2, units=hidden1_dim, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
    disc_logits = tf.layers.dense(disc_h1, units=1)
    disc_out = tf.nn.sigmoid(disc_logits)

return disc_logits, disc_out
```

nn version:

```
DC_D_W1 = tf.get_variable('DC_D_W1', shape=[5, 5, 1, 16], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
DC_D_b1 = tf.get_variable('2', initializer=tf.zeros(shape=[16]))

DC_D_W2 = tf.get_variable('3', shape=[3, 3, 16, 32], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
DC_D_b2 = tf.get_variable('4', initializer=tf.zeros(shape=[32]))

DC_D_W3 = tf.get_variable('5', shape=[7 * 7 * 32, 256],  initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
DC_D_b3 = tf.get_variable('6', initializer=tf.zeros(shape=[256]))

DC_D_W4 = tf.get_variable('7', shape= [256, 1],  initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
DC_D_b4 = tf.get_variable('8', initializer=tf.zeros(shape=[1]))

theta_DC_D = [DC_D_W1, DC_D_b1, DC_D_W2, DC_D_b2, DC_D_W3, DC_D_b3, DC_D_W4, DC_D_b4]

def discriminator(x):
    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])
    conv1 = tf.nn.leaky_relu(tf.nn.conv2d(x, DC_D_W1, strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME') + DC_D_b1)
    conv2 = tf.nn.leaky_relu(tf.nn.conv2d(conv1, DC_D_W2, strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME') + DC_D_b2)
    conv2 = tf.reshape(conv2, shape=[-1, 7 * 7 * 32])
    h = tf.nn.leaky_relu(tf.matmul(conv2, DC_D_W3) + DC_D_b3)
    logit = tf.matmul(h, DC_D_W4) + DC_D_b4
    prob = tf.nn.sigmoid(logit)

    return logit, prob
```

Comment: Could you link the example code you're following?

Comment: @Blacksilver https://gist.github.com/wiseodd/b2697c620e39cb5b134bc6173cfe0f56  - Loosely following that code, I was mainly looking at his conv2d design.